# Load function in Nim dll

Tags: windows, dll, dllimport, nim-lang

I have two files:

`foo.nim`:

```nim
 proc double*(x: cint): cint
    {.cdecl, exportc: "double", dynlib.} =
    return x * 2
```

`bar.nim`:

```nim
proc double(x: cint): cint
  {.cdecl, dynlib: "foo.dll", importc.}

echo double(2)
```

I compile `foo.nim` by running `nim c --app:lib foo.nim`, which generates `foo.dll`. When I run `bar.nim`, I expect it to load `double` from `foo.dll` and print `4`, but I get this error:

```
could not import: double
```

dllexp.exe only shows `NimMainInner`, so the function is not even being exported.

How can I import the `double` function from the dll? I plan on loading functions that might have the same name from multiple dlls, so a solution that can handle that would be preferred. I am running this on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**double** is reserved word in C. And **nim** compiles "double" function to something like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int double(int x0);
```

Somehow **vcc** can compile such code, but **gcc** don't.
But there is a workaround solution to rename "double" symbol during link stage

```
proc double*(x: cint): cint
    {.cdecl, exportc: "_double", dynlib.} =
    return x * 2

{.emit: """
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:double=_double")
""".}
```

The resulted dll will have original "_double" and "double" symbols

Comment: The naming of the function was a silly mistake, and renaming the function works perfectly. Also, is there a way to assign this proc to a variable so I can push the variable into a sequence?